# Executing a node script inside a golang project/file

Tags: node.js, go, exe

I'm trying to exec or run a node script inside my golang project. I'm using `os/exec`

```
data, err := exec.Command("node api.js", "resources/node/api.js").Output()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    output := string(data)

    fmt.Println(output)
```

this it the response I'm getting:

`panic: exec: "node api.js": executable file not found in %PATH%`

Not sure What I might be wrong or if there is an alternative way to execute this command. All I found was ways to  execute .sh command

Your assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1.you should use absolute path but relative path like```*/resources/node/api.js```  <br>2.api.js is param <br> ```data, err := exec.Command("node", "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\a.js").Output()```

Comment: `exec.Command("node", "api.js", ... )`

Comment: I'm getting ```panic: exit status 1```  on both tries @Volker @Parta

Answer (score 2):

I resolved it by using absolute paths for both the command and the file, here is a working code sample:

```
data, err := exec.Command("C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node", "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\project\\resources\\node\\api.js").Output()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    output := string(data)

    fmt.Println(output)
```